# Problem with animating in Android, using batcher.draw in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having a problem with the last part of the `GameRenderer` class. I call `batcher.draw()` and receive this error:

> The method draw(Texture, float, float, float, float) in the type SpriteBatch is not applicable for the arguments (Object, float, float, float, float)

This only happens when I try to draw animation; images work fine. How do I fix this?

---

This is my `GameRenderer` class, which throws the error.

```
public class GameRenderer {
    private SpriteBatch batcher = new SpriteBatch();

    public void render(float runTime) {
        // Begin SpriteBatch
        batcher.begin();
        // The bird needs transparency.
        batcher.enableBlending();

        // Draw bird at its coordinates. Retrieve the Animation object from
        // AssetLoader
        // Pass in the runTime variable to get the current frame.
        batcher.draw(AssetLoader.birdAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),
                x, y, width, height);

        // End SpriteBatch
        batcher.end();  
    }
}
```

---

Just in case, here is my `AssetLoader` class:

```
public class AssetLoader {
    public static Animation birdAnimation;

    public static void load() {
        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);

        TextureRegion birdDown = new TextureRegion(texture, 136, 0, 17, 12);
        birdDown.flip(false, true);

        TextureRegion bird = new TextureRegion(texture, 153, 0, 17, 12);
        bird.flip(false, true);

        TextureRegion birdUp = new TextureRegion(texture, 170, 0, 17, 12);
        birdUp.flip(false, true);

        TextureRegion[] birds = { birdDown, bird, birdUp };
        birdAnimation = new Animation(0.06f, birds);
        birdAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG);
    }
}
```

---

The class  where i call AssetLoader.load()

```
public class ZBGame extends Game {
    @Override
    public void create() {
        AssetLoader.load();
        /* Other stuff */
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are there two instances of this question? At any rate, is AssetLoader.load() ever called?

Comment: The first instance was before i signed up to the website, sorry.
and yes the asseloader.load function is called from my Create() function of the game, i added it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your last batcher draw in GameRenderer class to

```
batcher.draw((TextureRegion)AssetLoader.birdAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),
                bird.getX(), bird.getY(), bird.getWidth(), bird.getHeight());
```

Comment: that was my first attempt to fix it, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Animation` class is generic (see [docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html)) - meaning you should supply the type of object being animated which in your case would be `TextureRegion` since the keyframes are of type `TextureRegion`.

This means your code now becomes:

```
/* Declaration. */
public static Animation<TextureRegion> birdAnimation;

/* In your load() method. */
birdAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.06f, birds);
```